# Passing DB contents from XHTTP request

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I have an xhttp GET request to fetch the items in my db using its api gateway url.  The request works fine as I can see my db's contents which are in string (key:value pairs) from the browser's dev console.  Where I'm drawing a blank in is how to pass the db's contents to another function that parses it into javascript objects.

Fetch request code

```
function fetch(){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "<mygatewayapi_url>", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Code for parsing db contents into javascript object

```
function displayObj(dataStr){
    var obj = JSON.parse(dataStr);
    var html = "";
    var item =;
    //var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    //var last = keys[item.length - 1];

    for (item in obj){
        html += '<li>' + item + ' ' + obj[item] + </li>';
        /*if (last === true)
            html += '<li>' + item + ' ' + obj[item] + </li>' + "<br>";*/
    }
    return '<li>'+html+'</li>';
```

Comment: Need to show us a sample of the response and the request code you are using as per [mcve]

Comment: Where you have `console.log(this.responseText)`, have you tried `displayObj(this.responseText)`?

Comment: Phil, Thanks for the advice.  I tried it, and possibly works even though I now get the error, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2" which seems to be in the parsing code.

Answer (score 1):

You may handle the result in the `xhttp.onreadystatechange` callback:

```js
function fetch(){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var result = displayObj(this.responseText);
      console.log("result: \n", result); 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/emojis", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function displayObj(dataStr){
    var obj = JSON.parse(dataStr);
    var html = "";

    for (var item in obj){
        html += '<li>' + item + ' ' + obj[item] + '</li>';
    }
    return '<ul>'+html+'</ul>';
}

fetch();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```